# Batch file variable

Tags: batch-file

I have this code which echo the variable name...

```
set filename=
set filename=%1
```

... where `%1` is a command input from cmd

However when I run this batch file again which a different input, it still has the same value as before. When I run it again, then it has the value previously entered. How do I clear the variable so when I run the program again, it receives that input rather than the one before?

Comment: Is this fragment of code by any chance contained in an IF statement or, perhaps, in a loop body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it like so:

```
@echo off
setlocal
::set filename=
set "filename=%1"
pause
```

That should work.

Answer (score 2):

depending on your Windows version

setlocal

might do the trick for you